# authorization header ajax get with token session codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

authorization header ajax getting with a token session in Codeigniter, this is my reference https://github.com/dodistyo/ci-rest-jwt

I am just wanna try get data for ChartsJS, but not show data, i believe the problem in the authorization, because when i'm using GuzzleHttp that is works.

but failed using ajax.
this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      token = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('token')?>";
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            method: "GET",
            crossOrigin : true,
            headers: {'Authorization':"Basic <?php echo $this->session->userdata('token')?>"},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType : "jsonp",
```

i need your help, appreciate your help guys

Comment: Is this code in .js file or .html file?

Comment: .php, codeigniter

Comment: Not sure if that matters, but the example on the linked page has the actual token value in the Authorization header in double quotes …

Comment: with single quotes same not works bro @04FS

Comment: can you please check if $this->session->userdata('token') actually contains the token.

Comment: 'Authorization':'Basic eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgwMTE3OTc5LCJleHAiOjE1ODAxMjE1Nzl9.DfNZPMLLI2OcjBVpyOd-FurrXz230_P_5J7oIyUPNAM @Tsefo

Comment: I check in console source

Comment: Still shooting in the dark, but in ci-rest-jwt, instead of Basic they are using Bearer

Comment: Are you saying you tried `'Authorization':'Basic eyJ0eXAiOiJK…'` now? I was talking about the double quotes _in_ the header value, that the example has.

Comment: okay @Tsefo thanks,  I just tried and changed but still not work

Comment: @04FS oh yes, I just talk about the double quote you mention, I was changed for a single quote but still not working bro

Comment: Can you add an error to the ajax request and see what it actually returns?
error: function (data, status, xhr) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(xhr);
}

Comment: That’s not what I meant … I am talking about the difference between `Authentication: Bearer foobar` and `Authentication: Bearer "foobar"`. The github page you referred to explicitly uses the second version in their example.

Comment: @04FS oke I got it you meant, I just try for the first example is an error with red line for the example two, not error but the data, not showing

Comment: @Tsefo oke I'm on trying

Comment: @Tsefo just undefined bearer

Comment: @Tsefo error empty string bro

Comment: Does it show you in console that you in fact have an error or it is going to success function from the ajax request? you can test that easily with another console.log in error function, with dummy text

Comment: @Tsefo so far, I think the problem is a configuration for same access-control-allow-header, because if I use another link and token API that's working.
do you have an idea?

Comment: I'm getting the answer from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48678764/rest-controller-cors-not-working-codeigniter
thank you everyone